# Spark map and flatMap result types

Tags: scala, apache-spark

It looks like map and flatMap return different types.

`mySchamaRdd.map( p => Row.fromSeq(...))` returns org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.**sql.Row**] which is required for applySchema function (or createDataFrame in spark 1.3).

However, `mySchamaRdd.flatMap( p => Row.fromSeq(...)` returns org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[**Any**] and I cannot call applySchema().

How can I use applySchema() after flatMap()?

An example (input schema: Name, Description)

```
Bob, "Software developer"
John, "I like spaghetti"
```

Result:

```
Bob, Software
Bob, Developer
John, I
John, like
John, spaghetti
```

Comment: Why must you use flatMap if your map function returns a scalar?  flatMap is useful if you might output multiple, or occasionally no, records from your map function for each incoming record.

Comment: For each of row I'd like to return multiple rows. It's like text tokenizer.

An example for table Name, AboutMe

Bob, "Software developer"

John, "I like spaghetti"

Result:

Bob, Software

Bob, Developer

John, I

John, like

John, spaghetti

Comment: @Dmitry What if you embed the mapping of `flatMap` into a `Seq`? Something like this `mySchamaRdd.flatMap( p => Seq(Row.fromSeq(...)))` ?

Comment: @kaktusito Then the result will contain only 2 items: 1) Bob, Seq(...); 2) John, Seq(...). I expect to see all 5 items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I misunderstood the way you are creating your `SchemaRDD`, or maybe you misunderstood the way `flatMap` is supposed to work. Did you try this?

```
mySchemaRDD.flatMap( p => p.getString(1).split(" +").map( x => Row((p.getString(0), x))))
```

I think that `mySchamaRdd.flatMap( p => Row.fromSeq(...))` is not the appropriate use of `flatMap`, since you are supposed to return a sequence of things *embedded* in something, in order to *flat* it and extract what you really want to return. In your case, you are *embedding* it in a `Row`, while the result type you want to return is `Row` itself.

Comment: I want to add one more column to a pretty big schema. I use `map( word => p :+ word)` (in the last map). It looks like this code returns Seq<Any> which is root cause of the issue. After adding Row: `map( word => Row(p :+ word))` it works fine. Thank you for your help!

Comment: PS: The another solution - use one more map() after flatMap with Row: `mySchamaRdd.flatMap( p => Row.fromSeq(...).map(Row(_))`